# How to run getElementsByTagName on children of an element only?

Tags: javascript, selection, children, getelementsbytagname

I'm having trouble getting a selector to work properly.

I have this HTML:

```
<div.wrapper>
    <div.ui-controlgroup-controls>
        <form>
            <div.ui-btn></div>
        </form>
        <div.ui-btn></div>
        <div.ui-btn></div>
        <div.ui-btn></div>
        <div.ui-btn></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to select the `div` tags, which are children of `ui-controlgroup-controls` - which means excluding whats inside the form.

This is what I'm trying:

```
// el is my div.wrapper element
el.children[0].getElementsByTagName("div");
```

However this does not work, because the div inside the form ends up in the selection.

**Question**:
How can I select the elements correctly when I don't want to use jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to do this is to iterate over your resulting node list and check the parent:

```
var nodes = el.children[0].getElementsByTagName("div");
nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes);
nodes = nodes.filter(function(v, i){
    return v.parentElement === el.children[0]; 
});
```

Here is a demonstration of this approach: http://jsfiddle.net/WLhY2/

A simpler (albeit less efficient) approach is to use `querySelectorAll` to retrieve the relevant nodes using a selector expression:

```
var divs = document.querySelectorAll('div.ui-controlgroup-controls > div')
```

Comment: good idea. Waiting for a more complicated solution. Otherwise you get the nod! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For the browser that supports [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
var divs = el.children[0].querySelectorAll("div");
```

For the browsers that supports the usage of [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) on NodeList (e.g. not IE, at least not IE < 9):

```
var slice = Function.call.bind(Array.prototype.slice);

var divs = slice(el.children[0].children).filter(function(node) { 
               return node.tagName === "DIV"
           });
```

For the browsers that doesn't support neither:

```
var nodes = el.children[0].children;
var divs = [];

for (var l = nodes.length, node; node = nodes[--l];) {
  if (node.tagName === "DIV")
    divs.push(node);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives

Answer (score 1):

In most browsers, you can do:

```
el.querySelectorAll(".ui-controlgroup-controls > div")
```

---

But this could give false positives if there are more deeply nested `".ui-controlgroup-controls"` that you want to avoid.

If that's the case, just iterate the `.children`, and build a collection of nested divs.

```
var divs = [];

for (var i = 0, len = el.children.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (el.children[i].classname === "ui-controlgroup-controls") {
        for (var j = 0, lenj = el.children[i].children.length; j <, lenj; j++) {
            if (el.children[i].children[j].nodeName === "DIV") {
                divs.push(el.children[i].children[j])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

If it's known that you have only one `ui-controlgroup-controls` element, then you can get rid of the outer loop, and just use `children[0]`.

```
var divs = [];

for (var j = 0, lenj = el.children[0].children.length; j <, lenj; j++) 
    if (el.children[0].children[j].nodeName === "DIV") 
        divs.push(el.children[o].children[j])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<your-element>.querySelectorAll(":scope > div");
```

`:scope` is a pseudo-class representing the parent element. No support in IE, but there is a [shim](https://github.com/lazd/scopedQuerySelectorShim).