# Get count of direct children of specific type from div

Tags: javascript, html, children, getelementsbytagname

Im new to javascript and im trying to get a count of how many paragraphs each div has as direct children.

Example:

```
<div id="1">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <div id="2">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="3">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

The result im looking for:

- div 1 = 2
- div 2 = 1
- div 3 = 3

The code that i got so far looks like this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    var count = divs[i].getElementsByTagName('p').childElementCount;
    console.log('div ' + i + ' count ' + count);
}
```

The result:

[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yOd7.png)

Why do i get "undefined"? tried using .length instead of .childElementCount but that did not give me the desired result either.

Struggling to find a solution for this myself, jquery is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
  var count = divs[i].querySelectorAll(':scope > p').length;
  console.log('div ' + i + ' count ' + count);
}
```

```html
<div id="1">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <div id="2">
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="3">
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <p>text</p>
</div>
```

`:scope` means the parent element itself. `>` means to select the direct/immediate children.

Check out how `:scope` pseudo-class is currently supported [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll). No support from IE, but there is a [shim](https://github.com/lazd/scopedQuerySelectorShim) available.

Answer (score 3):

**First:**

`getElementsByTagName` is returning an Array like structure (HTMLCollection). You can get the list's length via `.length`.

You can use `childElementCount` on DOM-Objects only, not on collections.

**Second:**

`getElementsByTagName` will return all descendants, not only direct children. A solution to this was presented before on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750927/how-to-run-getelementsbytagname-on-children-of-an-element-only#15750959).
Don't forget to vote there, if you find the responses useful.

More efficiently, I'd recommend to just search through the children for div tags:

```
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    var children = divs[i].children,
        divCount = 0;
    for(var childIndex = 0; childIndex < children.length; childIndex++)
        if(children[childIndex].tagName == 'DIV')
            divCount++;

    console.log('div ' + i + ' count ' + divCount);
}
```

Or go more geeky about it and use `.reduce()` coupled with a reduce function.

Comment: Ok, i see now why ChildElementCount does not work but .length does not give me the desired result either.

Comment: No No, its not returning undefined. Its returning div0 count3, div1 count1, div2 count3. When what i would want is div0 count2, div1 count1, div2 count3. Tried putting example of result im looking for in main thread (starting to doubt if direct children is right term).

Comment: @DoesItRlyMatter There has been a very similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750927/how-to-run-getelementsbytagname-on-children-of-an-element-only#15750959

Comment: Will check it out!

Comment: @DoesItRlyMatter updated my answer. Hope it fixes the issue now. Hope to hear about it!

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```js
let divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div')

Array.prototype.slice.call(divs).map(div => {
  let count = 0;
  Array.prototype.slice.call(div.getElementsByTagName('p')).forEach(p => {
    if (p.parentNode == div) {
      count++;
    }
  })
  console.log('div ', div.id, " = ", count)
})
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="1">
    <p>text</p>
    <p>text</p>
    <div id="2">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="3">
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Sadly No, i get the same result if i change .ChildElementCount to .length in my code but what im looking for would be DIV 1 = 2, DIV 2 = 1, DIV 3 = 3.

Comment: I made some changes.  Take a look )